# How to import CSV to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.1.7
Ruby 2.1.4

I am trying to upload a CSV file to my app through a controller method:

routes.rb

```
get 'csv_upload', to: 'users#csv_upload'
```

users_controller.rb
    def csv_upload

```
 require 'csv'    

  customers = CSV.read('customers.csv')

  customers = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
  customers.each do |row|
    Moulding.create!(row.to_hash)
  end

  redirect_to users_url

end
```

CSV File customer.csv

```
gender ,age
10,20
11,20
12,20
13,20
14,20
15,20
```

It is located on the root directory. This is the error I get:

```
Errno::ENOENT in UsersController#csv_upload
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - customers.csv

Extracted source (around line #72):
70
71
72
73
74
75


customers = CSV.read('customers.csv')
customers = CSV.parse(customers, :headers => true)

Rails.root: /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/hackcdmx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it with a task:

lib/tasks/task.rake

```
namespace :tasks do
    require 'csv'

    desc "cargar usuarios"
    task :load_usuarios => :environment do |t, arg|
        user_files =['lib/datasets/customers.csv']
        user_files.each do |user|
            CSV.foreach(user,:headers => true) do |row|
                id = row.to_hash['id']
                gender = row.to_hash['gender']
                age = row.to_hash['age']
                User.create(id: id,gender: gender,age: age)
            end 
        end 
    end 
end
```

Created a folder named "datasets" and saved the file "customer.csv" here:

```
app/lib/datasets/customer.csv
```

Then executed the task through terminal

```
rake tasks:load_usuarios
```

Boom! Ready

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions says that file cant be found.

`customers = CSV.read('customers.csv')` is a relative path. It searches file in current working directory (probably not always in root). You can check working directory with, for example:

```
raise Dir.getwd.to_s
customers = CSV.read('customers.csv')
```

and an exception will show you current folder within what file gets searched.

To avoid this, you should better directly specify path with `Rails.root`, for example:

```
customers = CSV.read(Rails.root.join('customers.csv'))
```

Comment: Hi @Ablebeam, if I try raise Dir.getwd.to_s customers = CSV.read(Rails.root.join('customers.csv')) I get this runtime error: RuntimeError in UsersController#csv_upload

Comment: It is just one way to see what contains which variable. A better way is to use some debuggers like `pry` or `byebug`.
But in this case you should see something like

`RuntimeError: '/home/user/path/to/rails-app/or-other-directory'`

This is just to ensure that current (relative) path is not Rails.root